# Finding higher integer value

Tags: php, integer, rounding

```
echo    round(3.33);
```

returns me 3.

Is there any method available which returns the higher number, in this case 4?

Thanks,
Kay

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the function [`ceil()`](http://php.net/ceil).

Comment: Note: there is also a function called `floor` to round down.

Comment: Make sure that your links are pointing to the english version of the docs. I fixed that for you.